# Squeryl order by multiple columns

Tags: squeryl

I need to order by 2 fields:

```
SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY date ASC, sequence DESC;
```

Is it possible to emulate this SQL with Squeryl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by multiple fields. Just add them to the `orderBy`clause as below:

```
 from(table)(t => select(t) orderBy(t.date, t.sequence desc)
```